# How to connect a Javascript client with Red5 server?

Tags: javascript, red5

Anyone know how to connect a JavaScript client with Red5 Server?
I need to do this without flash, flash player or Java Virtual machine.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

You can write for example a servlet and invoke a REST call via JavaScript to the servlet. The servlet can then invoke a method and broadcast the message to all connected flash clients via RTMP.

Another possibility would be for example you integrate any other possibility to receive REST calls. Red5 is a regular Java Application server, normally deployed on Tomcat (or Jetty). So you could for example integrate Axis2 and have a full featured REST framework to handle JavaScript calls and forward those messages to the RTMP clients.

Sebastian